# After change server getting issue Ajax blocked if the site is on HTTPS

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, ajax, https

I have point to the website on another server. After that ajax has blocked on https url. If I run on HTTP then it is working fine.

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.exampple.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://www.example.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuY2hvY29sYWsuY29tLw,,/product/15/form_key/jPWQ3BJT3TgSpjS9/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
send @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6
ajax @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6
setcheckoutLocation @ (index):23
onclick @ (index):1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check once setting in back-end and try :

`Admin > System > Configuration > General > Web` , that `Use Secure URLs in Frontend` is set to `Yes`,and backend it to `Yes`.